# Problems with creating solr filter query with operator OR

Tags: solr

I have searchText and I want to search it in the several certain fields, not in the all defaults fields from schema.xml.
At first I tried in the solr admin http://localhost:8061/solr/admin/form.jsp to set
Query String (parameter "q") to the:
"field1:val OR field2:val"
But by some reason it doesn't work.

Then I tried to set FilterQuery (parameter "fq") to the:
"field1:val OR field2:val"

And it worked, but the problem was that architecture of our system is following:
we can only create separate filters, which after all will be linked by operator "AND".
In other words we create fq1, fq2,... and then our system perform f1=fq1 AND fq2 AND...

So, maybe somebody can advice some hack how to set this clause "field1:val OR field2:val"
to the fq1, for correct work of whole clause:
"f1=fq1 AND fq2 AND..."

Comment: What is defaultOperator in your schema.xml? is it AND?

Comment: Yes. But it would be better to don't touch schema.xml. Just to change query or filter query

Comment: try like this  fq=fieldName:(value1 OR value2)

Comment: my situation is a bit different. I want vice versa something like fq=value:(field1 OR field2). I mean I want to search one value in the two different fields.

Comment: build the query like fq=(field1:val1 OR field2:val1)...and so on..

Comment: you can build it to any complexity fq=(field1:val1 OR (field2:(val1 AND val2)))...

Comment: yes, but architecture of our system is bad. We must define fq only in format "field":"value". So I can set value to (field1:val1 OR field2:val1), but I also must set "field" to some value, for example "field1". And as a result we have fq=field1:(field1:val1 OR field2:val1).   Maybe there is some dirty hack for this situation?

Comment: hack how I can set "field" and "value"

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see this comment "fq=(field1:val1 OR (field2:(val1 AND val2)))"                                                                                                                     I'll try now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your usecase is good fit to Dismax/Edismax query parser in SOLR: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser

In particular:

```
qf  Query Fields: specifies the fields in the index on which to perform the query.
```

Comment: the problem with fq is that they don't undergo the same query pre-processing as the q parameter. However, fqs do support boolean logic.

Comment: Thanks you, it works good. There is only one issue. My query now is `{!type=dismax qf='name symbol'}test`.             But I want to find in this case, for example `testtt`. So how can I apply wildcards there?

Comment: {!type=dismax qf='name symbol'}test*